# Installing a switch that requires a neutral connection in a double gang box with two single pole switches

Tags: switch, home-automation

I am trying to install a switch that will replace a standard single pole switch that is in a 2 gang box like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDc25ncW1KVGtuSUk/view?usp=sharing).

[This is the documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDXzBRSktnUVhuWVE/view?usp=sharing) that I have on the device.  I tried wiring it but I must have had it wired wrong since it gave me an error when power was applied to it.

Comment: Does the box have 3 cables entering it, or only 2?  What are the colors of the wires in each cable?   Are there already any connections nutted together in the back of the box?

Comment: Do you have a non-contact voltage tester or a volt meter?

Comment: Can you get us some actual photos of what's inside the box?

Comment: @ ThreePhaseEel, @ Jim Stewart, @Harper https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDNVREblIxekNMY2M/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDekdpTEJNMVZ4UUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDekdpTEJNMVZ4UUE/view?usp=sharing) is photo of gang box

Comment: @JimStewart Yes, [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxGBUMKzqDlDNVREblIxekNMY2M/view?usp=sharing) is what I got for readings.

Comment: So when I attempted this the first time I connected the black on the new switch to the hot black of the Flourescent pair.  The Red wire to the other black in that same pair which I can only assume goes straight to the light. Then green to the bare copper and White to the rest of the white bundle.

After looking at this I am thinking that I probably had it mostly correct but I probably need to separate the neutral for the fluorescent from the rest of the bundle.

Comment: After thinking about that I realized there is still only one neutral that goes to the distribution box so both circuits would still need that common neutral, so there goes that theory.

Comment: I thought it would be worth it to remove the second switch from the equation and to wire it as if it were a single circuit like is provided in the instructions.  This would at least tell me if it is an issue with the switch of if it is a complication in the wiring.

Comment: It works!  Now if I add the second switch back in it will probably break it again, but I can't think of an alternative.

Comment: Second switch back in now, (basically how I wired it for my first trial that failed). It's still working!? hmm.....

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried this, maybe one of the wires was loose or something.  Anyway I connected the Black from the new switch to the hot black from the distribution box.  The green to bare copper, the white to the bundle of all the whites and the red to the other black that goes to the light.  For whatever reason it decided to work.